# Transition probability matrix for $X_1 = \# heads$, *flip heads* $X_2 = \# tails$ * flip tails* $X_3 = \# heads$

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Three fair coins are tossed, and we let $X_1$ denote the number of heads that appear. Those coins that were heads on the first trial (there were $X_1$ of them) we pick up and toss again, and now we let $X_2$ be the total number of tails, including those left from the first toss. We toss again all coins showing tails, and let $X_3$ be the resulting total number of heads , including those left from the previous toss. We continue the process. The pattern is, count heads, toss heads, count tails, toss tails, count heads, toss heads etc... and $X_0=3$. The ${X_n}$ is a Markov Chain. What is the transition probability matrix?

I thought the transition probability matrix would be this..
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1\\[0.3em]
0&0&0.5&0.5\\
0 & (0.5)^2 & 2(0.5)^2 & (0.5)^2 \\[0.3em]
(0.5)^3 &3(0.5)^3 &3(0.5)^3 &(0.5)^3\\
     \end{bmatrix}$$

where the state space is 0,1,2,3 .. is this correct?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: First define the states, please. Then one can tell if yours is the correct one.

Comment: I believe your matrix is correct as long as your coin is fair and you continue to alternate counting heads on odd steps and tails on even steps.